# Methods or considerations for aliasing commands

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to learn the right way of creating alias in the .bash_profile. For example, I was able to create different aliases for mongodb commands such as starting the server by only tying "mongod" keeping its path in the .bash_profile as: `alias mongod="mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf --fork"`, but when I searched how to create an alias for it so that it shutsdown the server by only tying `shutdown` as per to the mongodb docs, I could not do it but rather need to use this: `db.adminCommand({ shutdown: 1 })`

If I wanted to create an alias for this command `db.adminCommand({ shutdown: 1 })` or other ones in general, what are the right method or considerations should I take?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`db.adminCommand({ shutdown: 1 })` is not a bash command, it is a mongo shell helper.

In order to call that from the command line you would need to use the shell with the  `--eval` option:

```
mongo --host <hostname> --port <portnumber> --eval 'db.adminCommand({ shutdown: 1 })`
```

You should be able to assign that command line to an alias.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Joe should the line you've kindly provided be in the .bash_profile? Thanks again!